# Why is this button function crashing my tkinter GUI?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a GUI using tkinter, and this function that I assign to a button is causing my tkinter app to freeze, and I can't use the other buttons. Any ideas why?

```
def open_file():
    browse_text.set("loading...")
    path_to_watch = filedialog.askdirectory()
    
    print('Your folder path is"',path_to_watch,'"')
    
    old = os.listdir(path_to_watch)
    print(old)
    
    while True:
        new = os.listdir(path_to_watch)
        if len(new) > len(old):
            newfile = list(set(new) - set(old))
            newfile = str(newfile)
            newfile = newfile[2:36]
            print(newfile)
            global newpath
            newpath = os.path.join(str(path_to_watch), newfile)#do i need an argument for filetype?
    
            old = new           
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop, preventing `mainloop` from being able to service events and requests to refresh the display. Nothing will allow the code to break out of the loop.

Comment: the goal is to be constantly running and select a file when it is added to the folder of interest. Am I not able to do that with tkinter?

Comment: Do some research on the universal widget method `after`. There are many questions on this site related to it. Basically, you'll want to use `after` to run a function that performs some work and then uses `after` to schedult itself to run again in a few hundred milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem why your thing is crashing is because you have a while loop. Why? Because `root.mainloop()` will loop forever and you cannot have 2 while loops running simultaneously. However you can thread these loops or use `root.after()` function.

**1. Use `threading.Thread`**

Threading allows you to run multiple running processes at a time. Do this:

```
import threading

def open_file():
    browse_text.set("loading...")
    path_to_watch = filedialog.askdirectory()
    
    print('Your folder path is"',path_to_watch,'"')
    
    old = os.listdir(path_to_watch)
    print(old)
    
    def your_loop():
        while True:
            new = os.listdir(path_to_watch)
            if len(new) > len(old):
                newfile = list(set(new) - set(old))
                newfile = str(newfile)
                newfile = newfile[2:36]
                print(newfile)
                global newpath
                newpath = os.path.join(str(path_to_watch), newfile)
    
                old = new 
            else:
                continue
    
    threading.Thread(target=your_loop).start()
```

Basically we put the whole while loop to a function `your_loop` and then we called it using `threading.Thread`

**2. Use `root.after()`**

Another way to solve this problem is using `root.after()` method which I prefer to use. An advantage using this is that we can give small break for the while loop so that it doesn't run all the time. You basically tell what and when to run a specific command to the root. So you can basically repeat your function multiple times by doing this:

```
def open_file():
    browse_text.set("loading...")
    path_to_watch = filedialog.askdirectory()
    
    print('Your folder path is"',path_to_watch,'"')
    
    old = os.listdir(path_to_watch)
    print(old)
    
    def your_loop():
        # No while loops? Because we are repeating the function your_loop forever!
        new = os.listdir(path_to_watch)
        if len(new) > len(old):
            newfile = list(set(new) - set(old))
            newfile = str(newfile)
            newfile = newfile[2:36]
            print(newfile)
            global newpath
            newpath = os.path.join(str(path_to_watch), newfile)

            old = new 
        root.after(100, your_loop) # After 100 milliseconds run the function 'your_loop'
    your_loop() # Running the function for the first time
```

Hopefully this solves your problem